# Spring AOP @After annotation not running as expected

Tags: eclipse, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I am learning spring AOP, but I am having issues running the `@After` annotation.

For some reason, `@After` gets executed BEFORE the method call.

What am I doing wrong? Is it my Eclipse environment issue?

```spring
@Aspect 

public class LoggingAspect {

    @After("execution(* aop.*.* (..))")
    public void AfterLoggingAdvice() {
        System.out.println("AfterLoggingAdvice() is running");

    }

}
```

This is my main class:

```spring
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "aop.xml");

    ShapeService service = context.getBean("shapeService",
            ShapeService.class);
    System.out.println(service.getCircle().getName());

}
```

XML file:

```xml
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean id="circle" class="aop.Circle"  >
        <property name="name" value="Circle Name" /> 
        <property name="id" value="Circle ID" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="shapeService" class="aop.ShapeService"  autowire="byName"/>

    <bean id="loggingAspect" class="aop.LoggingAspect"/>

</beans>
```

This is the output regardless of using `@After` or `@Before`:

> AfterLoggingAdvice() is running
>
> AfterLoggingAdvice() is running
>
> Circle Name

Comment: It's working properly, this is just a poor test. The `@After` advice is being executed after (1) `aop.ShapeService#getCircle()` and (2) `aop.Circle#getName()` are executed. You are then printing the name of the circle in `main` after those methods have already been executed and values returned.

Comment: Add some `println` statements in your service and circle methods to see what I mean.

Comment: @superEb -  Thanks.. That did the trick....I moved the system out inside the getter() and now it prints out perfect.. :)